# Need help getting bash/batch to work for R on Windows 10

Tags: r, bash, batch-processing, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get batch mode working for R on Windows 10. The ultimate goal is to run many iterations of some R code in batch on an external server.

I successfully installed bash (unix wrapper for windows 10?) on my cmd prompt. I am working through a tutorial on using batch. I'm not sure if I want this to run through cmd or through the r code directly? https://github.com/gastonstat/tutorial-R-noninteractive/blob/master/02-batch-mode.Rmd

Via the tutorial I am working on testing batch/bash with simple code myscript1.R. Then the code I enter into cmd promp/bash looks like:

`R CMD BATCH "F:/Google Drive/Documents/batch/myscript1.R" "F:/Google Drive/Documents/batch/myscript1-output.R"`

Currently the closest I get in the cmd/bash is that an output file is created in the right folder but blank and I am told \usr\lib\R\bin\BATCH: cannot create myscript1-output.R: Permission denied.

I have done everything possible to allow full permissions to all users and not sure what is going on. Can anyone who knows how to use batch mode or bash in R for windows advised me?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to specify an output file; it writes a log automatically to the same directory as your script. What happens if you omit it?

Comment: Same thing - created a myscript1.Rout, but it's blank. /usr/lib/R/bin/BATCH: 60: /usr/lib/R/bin/BATCH: cannot create myscript1.Rout: Permission denied

Comment: `/usr/lib/R/bin` is a protected directory on linux, which is why it can't write the file there. Are you trying to run the script from within that directory? If so that would explain the error. Try navigating to the project folder with `cd`

Comment: Got part of it to work! Apparently I need to provide the location of R.exe then put CMD BATCH then put the dir for my R script:      

 "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "F:\Google Drive\Documents\Academics\GA Tech\Agony\wiki\batch\myscript1.R"

Answer (score 1):

Answer here thanks to Phil. I did not need to use "Bash" through Ubunto... I think.

Instead, I just needed to call the CMD BATCH through regular cmd with three parts:

1. the directory of my R.exe:  "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\R.exe"  (replace version)
2. CMD BATCH
3. directory of the project file/script: "F:\project_folders_batch\myscript1.R"
4. directory of the desired output (so it doesn't default to C/users/username). In this case, I output to the same folder as the script: "F:\project_folders_batch\myscript1-output.R"

Also, in case you are outputting plots or anything (I was), go ahead and cd (change directory) to the project folder before you do this. Final result in 2 steps:

1. cd /d "F:\projectfolder\batch"
2. "C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.3\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "F:\projectfolder\batch\myscript1.R" "F:\projectfolder\batch\myscript1-output.R"

Also mind your antivirus... it blocked access a few times.

Comment: Glad you got it to work. If you're at all used to Linux, or want to learn, you might find using terminal from WSL more useful than CMD, but at least you got something!